# Sporadic flickering for (very) long WS2812 strips

Tags: led, led-strip, rgb, ws2812b

I haven't found any information (almost anywhere, searching for weeks already) that goes beyond my research. I hope someone has a tip/idea/hint. Maybe my research helps others too.

---

Connected are 5120 (5 x 1024) WS2812 (non-B variant) on 4x4 PCB's (5 x 64 x 16 WS2812) to an ESP32. [PCB 4x4](https://nettigo.eu/products/rgb-4x4-ws2812b-matrix-on-pcb-with-mounting-holes)
1024 LEDs on a single pin.
5 individual multiplexed pins.
Data-wires are (from ESP32 3m to first WS2812, afterwards always < 50cm)

---

**Problem:**

The LEDs are 99% stable, sometimes flickering/color-changes happen for a single 'update-frame' (30-40ms), resulting that a 'strip' is being very disruptive. More towards the end; Beginning of the strip(s) almost never flicker(s).

Flickering is NOT uniform, one strip is stable, while another can flicker.

Full color white has less flickering, pinkish is the worst.

Updates happen (almost) as fast as possible. (~28-30 'fps')

Have tried many variations, none really 'solve' the flickering issue for good.

---

**Best results currently**:

(Should work for up to 512 LEDs without any issues [tested with 448 WS2812])

- Each pin/strip is controlled with the ESP32-RMT-Functionality. (Adafruit Neopixel library, FASTLED doesn't work, already tried)
- Each pin is first connected to an 74AHCT125 (3.3V -> 5V [datawire]), then to a 220 Ω (~22.3 mA / 5V), then to the WS2812 'strip'.
- Each strip's data is at the end, also connected to 220 Ω to GND to reduce data-wire-noise / wave-"bouncing". (220 Ω) (tested here 1 kΩ, 500 Ω, 220 Ω and 50 Ω), 220 Ω so far the best results)
- Each PCB has an individual power-connection to a power supply. Nothing in series, everything in parallel, to prevent voltage 'sagging'.
- Each strip has its individual power supply (5V * 60A | 300W each strip). (1500W in total) (required per PCB ~0.7A max (averaged and tested approx. 25 PCBs), so 300W should be more than enough, ~20% headroom)
- The ESP32 ground is connected with a 4.7 Ω to the common ground for all 5 power supplies. (power supplies without resistor) (+5V ESP32/individual strips are separate, GND is shared) (without the resistor between GNDs the flickering is even worse)

---

**Steps already taken:**

- Different level shifters (bi-directional, MOSFETs, directly connected without level-shifter)
- Different resistor values from ESP32 to LED-strip (difficult to evaluate)
- swapped order of resistor/level-shifter before connecting to LED strip (ESP32 -> 74AHCT125 -> 220 Ω -> WS2812 strip : so far best result)
- None or different 'data-wire-end-resistors' connected to GND
- Swapped the ESP32 3 times
- reduced the update frequency (using software) (no effect)
- higher software quantization of brightness values (4 bit, 6 bit and 8 bit) (using software) (no effect)

[image: Image for clarification]
The image shows the 'front' side of the installation. From right to left are leds connected. The leds are not just 'left to right', the connections are diagonal and the 'wooden plates' themselves have an internal pattern aswell. The diagram is/will be more complex, therefore i will provide a proper schematic soon.

Comment: Get rid of the resistors on the ground connections. If you put a 220 ohm on the source and a 220 ohm to ground (?), then you have made a 2:1 voltage divider which defeats the purpose of the 3.3v -> 5v level shifter. Try it without those things. If it still doesn't work, show your actual wiring and PCB layout.

Comment: resistors from data to ground aren't needed. Does each data wire have a ground wire alongside it?

Comment: [is this what you mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnOWK.png). A picture is worth a thousand words, and more organized too. Please provide a schematic, both of the power supply distribution, and of how the strips are connected, and any other PCB's that you're talking about, because you're set up is complicated that I'm not sure which PCB you're talking about when you say PCB. Even hand-drawn pictures on notebook paper is better than nothing.

Comment: You said you searched, but did you try a [Google search of "ws2812b" "flickering"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ws2812b%22+%22flickering%22)

Comment: Hello, sorry i was out of country.

I will provide a schematic/image soon. Thanks you very much for your input.

I was already aware already of the voltage division properties. Ive measured the ins and outs with an oscilloscope though.

If there are no resistors at the end, i have more wave-ringing effects in the datawire measured. That the electrons seem to bounce back in forth in the wire. (Also talked to a engineering prof of mine)

Not really, there are these: [WS2812 - 4x4](https://nettigo.eu/products/rgb-4x4-ws2812b-matrix-on-pcb-with-mounting-holes) we 320 use in the project